# How to correctly paste HTML into C# code with Visual Studio or Resharper (or any other tool!)?

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resharper

Is there any way to make a "safe" paste into Visual Studio (C#) of HTML code? If I try to paste something like

```
<div class="user-info"><div class="user-action-time">answered <span title="2010-09-16 02:23:16Z" class="relativetime">21 mins ago</span>
```

into my code, C# will cry. Using the @ operator doesn't help us, either.

Is it possible to make a special paste in Visual Studio (2010) or Resharper?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **SmartPaster** Extention.

After install `Right click -> Paste As... ->  Paste as @String`

**Download links**

- [SmartPaster for Visual Studio 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=martinw.SmartPaster)
- [SmartPaster for Visual Studio 2019 and earlier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=martinw.SmartPaster2013)

Comment: Doesn't seem to support what I am asking for. Does it?

Comment: devoured, maybe I misunderstood what you wanted. But Smart Paster will take the content of your clipboard and pasted into your c# class as a string, escaping the characters properly and all. so if you have the content - I am a "string" - in your clipboard, it will paste the following into your code: @"I am a \"string\""
I thought that's was what you were after. If that is not, sorry to have wasted your time.

Answer (score 5):

Use @, select pasted text and replace `"` with `""` in the selection. That's what I do when I paste text containing quotes.

Comment: This is exactly what smart paster do.

Answer (score 1):

So none of the above worked for me!  Copying a large multi-line code snippet from a web page and pasting into VS2010 always reulted in a single line with no linefeeds.  The quickest work-around was to **paste the HTML into MS Word and then copy this and paste it into VS2010**.  HTH, Matt

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this?

http://www.clipboardfusion.com/

I don't have any personal experience, but it seems like a flexible way to perform any kind of manipulation to the clipboard you like (since you can define transforms in C#) and it's free. As noted by Alex, just doubling up on double-quotes should be fine, providing you preface the string with an '@' and this won't even need any code - just a simple string search / replace.